# GWT widget: top page popdown message bar - similar to the one here on stackoverflow

Tags: gwt, widget

Has anyone seen or have an idea on how to go about creating widget that would function like the pop-down message bar here at stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented one with absolute positioning.  My entire page is generated by GWT, so it was (relatively) easy to use RootLayoutPanel.get().add(popupWidget), and then use RootLayoutPanel.get().setWidgetTopHeight(), etc, to animate the thing on and off the screen.